# elasticsearch different scoring boost for specific search term frequency

Tags: elasticsearch

I have article1 and article2 objects in ES, both contain "the brown fox jumped" and "darkness is a friend", however, more people seem to click on article1 after searching for "the brown fox jumped", and more people seem to click on article2 after searching for "darkness is a friend". Yet, some people do the opposite, but they're not the majority.

I somehow want to ensure score goes up for article1 when searching "the brown fox jumped" as it registers more clicks. Same goes for article2 and "darkness is a friend".

Let's say I can increment click count inside the ES object based on specific search terms used to find them. How would I construct this information into ES and how would the query look like?

thanks!